How can I connect a CHW1010-ANT1-1.0-ND to an nrf5340 development board?
I would like to connect a CHW1010-ANT1-1.0-ND to an nrf5340 development board to implement direction finding.
This is in the datasheet of the CHW1010-ANT1-1.0

The nrf5340 has a Murata MM8130-2600RA2 (J1)

Is it possible to use this antenna array with the nrf5340 development board? What connectors/cables would I need for this?

I won't answer on the adapter, as product recommendations are off topic on this page. Just search your preferred distributor for "X to Y adapter 50 ohm" and make sure you get the bandwidth >3GHz, and the connector genders right.
According to the documentation of the NRF5340 DK, the connector is not meant to be used for an external antenna, but for doing RF measurements.:

The nRF5340 DK is equipped with a small coaxial connector (J1) for conducting measurements of the RF signal with a spectrum analyzer.
The connector is of Microwave coaxial connector with switch (SWF) type (Murata part no. MM8130-2600) with an internal switch. By default, when no cable is attached, the RF signal is routed to the onboard trace antenna.

